# How to load PHTML file last after page is fully loaded

Tags: module, javascript, phtml, page, loader

I have a script in my phtml file but I want to only load this ones the page is fully loaded.
I am doing a check if my custom module is enabled show the < script >

Adding script like this :

You can achieve this using template call

```
<referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Namespace_Modulename::before.phtml" name="before_body_js"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

Can anyone give me a advice or help to figure this out

```
<script>
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "My First JavaScript";
</script>
```

I have to use this as well

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  alert("This alert box was called with the onload event");
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's a script, you can try wrapping your script code inside

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 // Your code
});
```

This will ensure that your code written inside will be reflected once the page is loaded.

Comment: I have added a script in my question this is what I am trying to add

Answer (score 1):

**domReady!** - You can use this feature of the RequireJS like the native Magento's modules use:

```
<script>
    //<![CDATA[
    require(
        [
            'jquery',
            'domReady!'
        ], function($) {
            // Your Code
        });
    //]]>
</script>
```

**DOMContentLoaded** - Executes after DOM is loaded (before img and css):

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "My First JavaScript";
});
```

**load** - Executes after everything is loaded and parsed:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "My First JavaScript";
});
```

Comment: I have updated the question with the script I am trying to pass.

Comment: Please check updated answer.

Comment: I have added one more script can I still use the same method?

Comment: Yes you can add.

Comment: How would I do that please can you show me

Comment: Can you please update/share whole code?

Comment: Done I have added the thing I need to add